# Yii framework-1.1.14.f0fee9 zend_mm_heap corrupted, exceed Maximum execution time

Tags: php, cron, centos, yii1.x

This is problem i get when doing a mass Edit as a cron job. (more than 15 000 records)

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /frameworks/yii/framework-1.1.14.f0fee9/db/schema/CDbCommandBuilder.php on line 0
> zend_mm_heap corrupted

I set the time and memory as bellow

```php
set_time_limit(0); //no time limitation
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); // no memory limitation
```

After applying this code, again getting

> Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /frameworks/yii/framework-1.1.14.f0fee9/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php on line 407
>
> Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /frameworks/yii/framework-1.1.14.f0fee9/validators/CValidator.php on line 0
> Segmentation fault

I need to handle more than 2 lacks records.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What does `ini_get('safe_mode')` give?